# Equal Width Tab Items Generated Dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am creating tabs that needs to be equal in width, it will come dynamically (2-8 tabs). There is no fixed width, tab bar has fluid width. I had tried to achieve it through css, but didn't worked.

demo:http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JdbMwR

```
<div class="main">
<ul class="list-inline sub-cat-tabs">
  <li>
    <div>
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="active"><span>2014-2015 2014-2015</span></a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div>
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class=""><span>2015-2015</span></a> 
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yNVpZm you mean this?

Comment: You should try to put the style on the divs: width:120px;

Comment: You may want to look at Flexbox https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: @sdcr, There would be 2-8 tab inside the bar. Tabs should always occupy the equal width and should cover full width of the bar.

Comment: @jlego cant use flex box as it wont support below IE11. I believe the only solution would be jquery and i am not good in it.

Comment: @Praveen, you should edit your question to include what browsers you need to support.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it with CSS fixed table layout, browser support: IE8+

http://jsfiddle.net/gashvbp6/

```css
.tabs {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: table;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}
.tabs li {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<ul class="tabs">
    <li>item - long one</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
</ul>
```